# XSD defines schema for WDSL - how to interpret

Tags: xml, wsdl, xsd

I am reviewing a XSD document that is supposed to define WSDL web services. Looking at
ftp://ftp.ihe.net/TF_Implementation_Material/ITI/schema/IHE/RFD.xsd I am unable to tell how to translate this XSD into meaningful web service contracts. Do some tools exist that would automagically parse the XSD and create a stub of a web service? How am I to interpret the XSD to a WSDL contract? -- snippet below...

```
<xs:complexType name="workflowDataType">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="formID" type="xs:string">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>The identifier of the form to be retrieved.</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="encodedResponse" type="xs:boolean" default="true">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
true - return either Structured or Unstructured inline form content false - return a URL to the form
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="archiveURL" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="0">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
The URL that the Form Filler provides to the Form Manager so that the returned form can have the archive location prefilled.
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="context" type="anyXMLContentType" nillable="true">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>tbd an IHE Content Profile</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="instanceID" type="xs:string" nillable="true">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
An optional form instanceID returned by the Form Manager
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

As XSD by itself does not define a Web service - it just defines the data that is going to be transmitted/received via the Web service (actually, the XML representation of the data).

What is missing is the definition of the actual Web service calls - for that there is the WSDL file, that is different from the XSD.